# NativeStreamHandle can't be Zero in Kinect SDK

Tags: kinect

I was working in a kinect class, it was all right until this error appear:

```
NativeStreamHandle can't be Zero
```

in the line of code:

```
_nuiRunTime.DepthStream.GetNextFrame(20);
```

This not happen in:

```
 _nuiRunTime.SkeletonEngine.GetNextFrame(20);
```

Any ideas?

**Update:**
I fixed the bug. Apparently the resolution  was wrong. I have to change the resolution of the deapthstream

```
ImageResolution.Resolution640x480  to ImageResolution.Resolution320x240.
```

The kinect sdk's documentation say that the following depth data streams are available:

•   Frame size of 640×480 pixels
•   Frame size of 320×240 pixels
•   Frame size of 80×60 pixels

It's a bug of the Kinet SDK?

--sorry if my english is poor.. =)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you forgot to include the depth stream in your initialization code?  Something like:

```
        kinect = new Runtime();
        kinect.Initialize(RuntimeOptions.UseColor | RuntimeOptions.UseSkeletalTracking | RuntimeOptions.UseDepthAndPlayerIndex);
        kinect.DepthStream.Open(ImageStreamType.Depth, 2, ImageResolution.Resolution320x240, ImageType.DepthAndPlayerIndex);
```